# How to redirect to CPQ Quote Line Editor page in an action/button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, cpq

I am trying to implement a button/action to redirect directly from opportunity to related quote line editor.

However, quote line editor is no longer a VF page now. I am not even sure whether it is a lightning component or not. Is there any way I can redirect from apex code/javascript to redirect to that page?

Comment: Why do you think edit lines isn't a VF page? The button on my quote is a VF page: SBQQ.EditLines2

Comment: @DanielHoechst I am not sure by the one you mentioned as I don't see a VF page called EditLines. But I do see one called EditQuoteLines which seems to be the old version of QLE. The page sb seems more appropriate but still missing the headbar

Comment: @DanielHoechst never mind, I have used apply sb VF page and it works fine now. Thank you for that

Comment: Oops, that's the right one. EditLines2 is the name of the button.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar very recently for a demo. As far as I know its a visualforce page. I created a new lightning quick action button on opportunity. The idea is to create a quote with account and opportunity and navigate them to the relevant Quote Line Editor. Specifically look for **`navigateToQLE`** to pick up the url for navigation in the lightning experience.

**MarkUp:**

```
<aura:component controller="CSSCreateNewQuoteFromOppCtrl"
                description="CSSCreateNewQuote" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="oppRecord" type="Opportunity" />

    <!-- Handling it onchange of attribute instead
    on init because force:recorddata isn't fetching data onload-->
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.oppRecord}"
                  action="{!c.onOpportunityLoad}"/>
    <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                      targetFields="{!v.oppRecord}"
                      fields="Id, Name, AccountId"/>

    <!-- <div>
        <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" />
    </div> -->

    <!-- Using custom spinner to apply the relative class for the spinner-->
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium slds-is-relative">
        <div class="slds-spinner_container">
            <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--small" role="alert">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading...</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
({
    onOpportunityLoad: function(component,event, helper) {
        var oppId = component.get("v.oppRecord.Id");

        if (oppId != null && oppId !== undefined) {
            console.log('oppId not null');
            helper.fetchQuote(component);
        }
    }
})
```

**Helper.js**

```
({
    fetchQuote : function(component, callback) {
        console.log('entered fetch quote');
        var action = component.get("c.createQuote");
        action.setParams({
            opp : component.get("v.oppRecord")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('success from server');
                console.log("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
                var quote = response.getReturnValue();
                this.navigateToQLE(component,quote);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error occured from server");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    navigateToQLE :function(component,quote){
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": 'https://ccrazedev-dev-ed--sbqq.na78.visual.force.com/apex/sb?scontrolCaching=1&id='+quote.Id +'#quote/le?qId='+quote.Id 
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }

})
```

> **Note:** This is the URL I picked from classic as lightning is masking the URL. I was navigated to back to quote on save and cancel
>   of the QLE. I guess the page is kind of detecting the UI context, so I
>   didn't face any issues except, I was hit with an **error** when trying
>   to delete the quote immediately.I was able to delete the quote from
>   opportunity without any issue though. I didn't dig deeper into it, but
>   just wanted to give you a heads-up anyway. You might want to try
>   playing around with this Url to fine tune it. Last but not least not
>   this sure if this is the right way to do it, so use it at your own
>   discretion.

Answer (score 1):

This Apex works for both classic and Lightning

Given a button that creates a quote and then redirects the user to the quote line editor

```
public PageReference saveNewQuote() {
    // was: PageReference resPg = Page.SBQQ__EditQuoteLines; pre Spring 18
    PageReference resPg = Page.SBQQ__SB;
    SBQQ__c.Quote__c q;
    try {
      q = new SBQQ_Quote__c(field1 = x, ...);
      insert q;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new 
            ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
        return null;
    }
    resPg.getParameters().put('scontrolCaching','1');
    resPg.getParameters().put('id',this.q.Id);  
    resPg.setRedirect(true);
    return resPg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Lighting Web Component, you can import the lightning-navigation service function to redirect a User to another page in Salesforce. See more on where you can use the [lightning-navigation service here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate). This can be used to redirect a user to the QLE.

To use the lightning-navigation service in your LWC, you must import the `NavigationMixin` function from the `lightning-navigation` service. You must extend the components base class with `NavigationMixin` to gain access to its APIs.

In the following example, a User clicks a button that calls the `saveMethod()`. This method calls an Apex Controller that has also been imported called `createdNewQuote`. This Apex Method takes the Opportunity record Id as a parameter, which is found using the `$recordId` syntax and the fact that this LWC is on an Opportunity detail page. The Apex Controller returns a newly created Quote object and it's `Id`. In the callback method, a url is created using the returned Quote objects record `Id`.

This url is then used in the `NavigationMixin.Navigate` method. To redirect a User to the QLE, the `type` must be set to `standard__webPage` which is used to redirect users an external URL, but works to redirect a User to a VisualForce page as well.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import createNewQuote from '@salesforce/apex/apexController.createNewQuote';
import { NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class lwc_class extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  @api recordId;

  saveMethod(){

    createNewQuote({recordId: '$recordId'})
         .then( result  => {

              let link = '/apex/sbqq__sb?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + result.Id 
                       + '#quote/le?qId=' + result.Id;

              this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                   type: 'standard__webPage',
                   attributes: {
                        url: link
                   },
                   true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
              });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error: ', error);
        });

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this answer is what we call a _code dump_. It's a block of code with little/no explanation as to how it works or how it solves the issue at hand. Code dumps tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" that make it hard for other people reaching this question from, say, a google search to apply. This answer would be improved if you were to [edit] your answer to explain (at least) the important bits about how this approach works.

Comment: It works for me in LWC. Thanks